# How to remove "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'OldController' is not a function, got undefined"?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to learning AngularJs and stuck at this particular error. Can't seem to find the reason behind this error. Any help will be appreciated.
I am using AngularJs 1.2.
Please advise.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
       <body ng-app="Heirarchy">
            <div ng-controller="ParentController">
            <div ng-controller="ChildController">
            <a ng-click="sayHello()">Say hello</a>
            </div>
            {{ person }}
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("Heirarchy",[]);
            app.controller("ParentController",function($scope){
            $scope.person = {greeted:false};
            });
            app.controller("ChildController",function($scope) {
            $scope.sayHello = function(){
            $scope.person.name="Blade";
            $scope.person.greeted = true;
        }
      });
   </script>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: why you have 2 ng-app ! and one of them is null and other one have a value!?

Comment: There is no way that the code you posted here could create the error you have in the title.

Comment: besides that, if you are going to use a legacy version of angular, you should at least use the supported version of it (1.2.29) instead of a deprecated Release Candidate with compatibility issues.

Comment: No controller you used in the name of 'Old Controller'.

Comment: Remove extra ng-app from html as mentioned by @AnikIslamAbhi it will work check oout plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/vjrGwLHFRxQC8ji3gaFa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Update your code

> Insert ng-app="your module name" in your html tag, and do not repeat ng-app in your app

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Heirarchy">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ParentController">
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        <a ng-click="sayHello()">Say hello</a>
    </div>
    {{ person }}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module("Heirarchy", []);
        app.controller("ParentController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.person = { greeted: false };
        });
        app.controller("ChildController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.sayHello = function () {
                $scope.person.name = "Blade";
                $scope.person.greeted = true;
            }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Maher, Stupid Mistake.